# Call a function when clicking on the "X" of md-autocomplete (Angular Material)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

How can I call a function (defined by me) when clicking on the cross (X) that clears the text of Angular Material's autocomplete?

[Link to md-autocomplete] (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct click event for the clearance button of `md-autocomplete` but you can detect when the text gets cleared using the `md-search-text-change` event:

```
function searchTextChange(text) {
  if (!text) {
    console.log("text got cleared")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ver much for your answer, @Akis. But unfortunately, that's not a solution that I can use.

Comment: @ErickRamírez what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Make a call to a rest service when the user clears the input using the cross. If I use the searchTextChange function the way you wrote it, I might be making the call when I'm not supposed to.

Comment: if you really need the click event then you can find it using a selector like this `$('md-autocomplete button')` then you can add a onClick event.